# COUNT and GROUP BY in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this query and it does a couple of joins, but I want to do a `Count` and the way it is now it gives a count of 1 for everyone. What am I doing wrong to make it so it actually Counts? Thanks!

```
SELECT
  UserColder.ContactName,
  CountryUser.[User ID],
  COUNT(Country.Name) As num,
  Country.Name,
  Country.ID
FROM
  dbo.Country
  INNER JOIN dbo.CountryUser
    ON Country.ID = CountryUser.[Foreign ID]
  INNER JOIN dbo.UserColder
    ON CountryUser.[User ID] = UserColder.ID
WHERE
  EXISTS
  (SELECT
    NULL
   FROM
    CountryUser CU2
   WHERE
    CU2.[Foreign ID] = CountryUser.[Foreign ID]
    AND CU2.[User ID] <> CountryUser.[User ID])
    GROUP BY UserColder.ContactName, CountryUser.[User ID], Country.Name, Country.ID
```

EDIT:

My data looks like:

```
Bob   United States
Tom   United States
Steve United Stated

Frank Canada
Billy Canada

Lou   China
```

So next to the United States it should be 3 and Canada 2 and China 1.

Comment: Could you provide some illustration result data? You want count of which column based on which others columns?

Comment: What exactly do you want to count?

Comment: Shouldn't you group your query by `Country.Name` if you want a count of each name?  I think you basically have a bunch of groups of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count users per country, a [window function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) is one possibility. Could look like this:

```
SELECT u.ContactName
      ,cu.[User ID]
      ,c.Name
      ,c.ID
      ,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.ID) AS users_in_this_country
FROM   dbo.Country     AS  c
JOIN   dbo.CountryUser AS cu ON c.ID = cu.[Foreign ID]
JOIN   dbo.UserColder  AS  u ON cu.[User ID] = u.ID
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   CountryUser AS cu2
    WHERE  cu2.[Foreign ID] = cu.[Foreign ID]
    AND    cu2.[User ID] <> cu.[User ID])
    )
```

I also used table aliases to shorten the syntax (no change to functionality) and removed `GROUP BY` in the `EXISTS` subquery because it was without function.

---

#### How to filter by result of window function?

In response to comment: in your case you already implemented this particular filter with the `EXISTS` clause.

Generally, to filter by the result of a window function, use a subquery or a CTE like this:

```
;With cte AS (
   < query from above >
   )
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  users_in_this_country > 1
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for that help! Last question how do a filter by users_in_this_country > 1? Thanks!

Comment: @Justin: I added another answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a sub-query in the select part of the outer query and join it to the outer query. For example it should look something like this. Hopefully that helps.

```
SELECT
  UserColder.ContactName,
  CountryUser.[User ID],
  (SELECT COUNT(C2.Name) FROM dbo.Country C2 INNER JOIN dbo.CountryUser CU2
    ON C2.ID = CU2.[Foreign ID]
    WHERE UserColder.ID = CU2.[User ID])  As num,
  Country.Name,
  Country.ID
FROM
  dbo.Country
  INNER JOIN dbo.CountryUser
    ON Country.ID = CountryUser.[Foreign ID]
  INNER JOIN dbo.UserColder
    ON CountryUser.[User ID] = UserColder.ID
```